# Updating GridView After taking a picture

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm new to this android programming but I've been looking up and down for an anwser for this.

The app takes a picture and then presents it to the user in a gridView, but the problem is, it doesn't show it until you close the app, and go to the built in gallery of the phone to see the pictures, when you enter the app again it shows everything normal again.

Heres the code:

The xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/cheese" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

The main activity:

```
    package com.example.camerainteration;

import java.io.File;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button camera;
    ImageView imagem;
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;
    GridView sdcardImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.camera);
        camera.setOnClickListener(this);
        refresh();



    }

private void refresh(){
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);

    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

private void TakePhoto() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/");


    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);




    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);
                // Move cursor to current position
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // Get the current value for the requested column
                int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
                picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                picturesView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            }
            else {
                picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.camera:
            TakePhoto();
            refresh();
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Put all the code below setContentView to TakePhoto() method. Just underneath startActivityForResult

Comment: But that would start the camera in the begining and I don't want that. I want the user to see what pictures are in the gridview, click the button to take a picture, and when the camera closes and returns to the app show the new taken picture in the gridview, which the latter is not happening. It takes the picture fine and stores it in the following dir: mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/ but when I want to see the new picture it doesn't show until I exit the app, go to the built in gallery, return to the app and there it is. I've no idea why this happens

Comment: But did it work the way i said

Comment: Ok i have found anotherway for you. Leave your code as before and instead of `sdcardImages.invalidateViews()` use `sdcardImages.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: user3033613: No, the camera started, and I took a picture, bur the gridview didn't updated with the new picture

Has for the sdcardImages.notifyDataSetChanged() it's giving me an error, and the solution it provides is the following:

1º-Change to  sdcardImages.deferNotifyDataSetChanged()

2º-Add cast to sdcardImages

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID}; 

cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, // Which columns to return null, // Return all rows null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);


columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID); 

sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Put above code inside a method and call it twice. Once in the onCreate and then after you take the pic

Comment: I updated the code and added your advicee, but it still doens't refresh the gridview with the new picture that was taken...by the way, I want to refresh the gridview or the gridview adapter? I'm kinda confused...

Comment: No change to the app at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the **refresh** immediately after returning from TakePhoto. You need to implement onActivityResult method and then do a refresh from there. You are already doing the right thing by doing the **startActivityForResult**.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            refresh()
        }
    }
```

One more thing. You may not need to call refresh at all. You can just do the **notifyDataSetChanged** on the adapter and that should work also.

Good luck.